# How can I find out if any one item in a Python list is in a string using regex?

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I have a list and I'd like to find out if any one item in that list is in a string using regex. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Note that you have not accepted any answers to other questions you have asked - this is likely to put people off answering this one.

Comment: @Lattyware: 't has been a long day, perhaps I need to knock off.. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I thought the same thing at first.

Comment: It's a hard question to read.

Comment: @Lattyware -- Yeah it is.  I'm not even sure my answer is right ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.

```
myregex = re.compile(...)
print any(myregex.search(s) for s in my_list_of_strings)
```

or maybe:

```
regexs = [re.compile(s) for s in my_list_of_regex_strings]
any(r.search(my_string) for r in regexs)
```

which I suppose is probably the same thing as :

```
regex_str = '|'.join('(?:%s)'%re.escape(s) for s in list_of_regex_strings)
re.search(regex_str,my_string)
```

I still can't tell which way you're trying to go with this...

Finally, if you actually want to know which regex matched:

```
next(regex_str for regex_str in regex_str_list if re.search(regex_str,mystring))
```

This will raise a `StopIteration` exception (that you can catch) if none of the regex's match.

Comment: I think he wants to do the opposite if this, where he starts with a list of search targets, then finds all of them that occur in a given string.

Comment: @sr2222 -- I've re-read the question about 6 or 7 times now and I'm still not sure ...

Comment: "find if any one item in [a] list is in a string" leads me to think he has a set of targets and wants to see if any of them show up in the string.  So basically `match` with a bunch of or'ed values in the pattern.  Or even just `any(x for x in targets if x in string)`.

Comment: @mgilson sr2222 has it correct except I want to find the first time a member of the list is found in the string and then return the member that it finds or otherwise return None. Can that be done?

Comment: `next( (res for res in re.search(pattern, string) for string in strings if res), None)` or something then...

Comment: @ceradon -- See my last example.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that OP is asking how to *to find out if any one item in a list of strings matches a pattern using regex*.

```
# import the regex module
import re

# some sample lists of strings
list1 = ['Now', 'is', 'the', 'time', 'for', 'all', 'good', 'men']
list2 = ['Me', 'Myself', 'I']

# a regex pattern to match against (looks for words with internal vowels)
pattern = '.+[aeiou].+'

# use any() around a list comprehension to determine
# if any match via the re.match() function
any(re.match(pattern, each) for each in list1)

# if you're curious to determine just what is matching your expression, use filter()
list(filter(lambda each: re.match(pattern, each) , list2))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for each item in list:
   use regex on string
```

thats as specific as possible given the generalistic nature of your question.

EDIT: this is psuedocode, not python